# srcset not working on img

Tags: html, image, reactjs, srcset

I have a [React SimpleImage component](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/blob/glamor/app/SimpleImage.js) which uses `srcSet` to use the srcset property on the img.

The component has the code:

```
const image = (<img
    {...imageStyle}
    src={src}
    srcSet={srcsetStr}
    alt={alt}
    width={width}
    height={height}
    role="presentation"
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onError={onFail}
  />);
```

The image is placed in a `div`:

```
return (<div {...wrapperStyle}>
    {statusIndicator}
    {image}
  </div>);
```

The wrapperStyle is defined as:

```
const mainWrapperStyle = style({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    backgroundRepeat: 'none',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    position: 'relative',
    width,
    height,
 }
```

The width on the div is the same as the width on the `img`..

I get an error in the generated markup's `srcsert` property which looks like this:

```
<img 
  srcset=" https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png 1x  
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png 2x 
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-3x.png 3x 
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-4x.png 4x" width="800px" 
    height="800px" role="presentation" 
    src="https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png" 
    data-css-44fijj="[* + *]"
>
```

I have an error here:

```
DOMPropertyOperations.js?17f3:142 Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `srcSet` instead of `srcset`:

```
<img 
  srcSet=" https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png 1x  
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png 2x 
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-3x.png 3x 
    https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-4x.png 4x" width="800px" 
    height="800px" role="presentation" 
    src="https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png" 
    data-css-44fijj="[* + *]"
>
```

[More info in the react docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html)

Comment: I used `srcSet` in my component, the `srcset` attribute in the generated markup causes an isssue: https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/blob/glamor/app/SimpleImage.js

Answer (score 0):

```
import meal1x from '../images/meal.jpg';
import meal2x from '../images/meal@2x.jpg';
import meal3x from '../images/meal@3x.jpg';

<img
    className='meal'
    src={meal1x}
    srcSet={`${meal1x} 1x, ${meal2x} 2x, ${meal3x} 3x`}
  />
```